# Specify command line arguments in a visual studio 2017 cmake project

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I have a cmake project in visual studio VS2017. Lets say this project creates an application `my_app.exe`. For debugging I want to start the application with some command line arguments like this:

```
my_app.exe --option1 "Hello World"
```

how can I tell visual studio to do that?